# how to use forEach with slf4j.logger.info

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, log4j, slf4j

I am developing a simple application based on Spring Batch, Spring Boot, slf4j, and Java 8. I want to use lambda as much as possible for learning purposes. What is wrong with

```java
myPojos.stream()forEach((myPojo)-> {log.info(myPojo);});
```

below? The message complains

> ...is not applicable for the arguments `<? extends MyPojo`.

Kindly, note that all other three log lines are working correctly.

```
public class CustomItemWriter implements ItemWriter<MyPojo> {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomItemWriter.class);

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends MyPojo> myPojos) throws Exception{
        myPojos.stream().forEach((myPojo)-> {log.info(myPojo);});//error
        myPojos.forEach(System.out::println);//it works
        myPojos.stream().forEach((myPojo) -> {System.out.println(myPojo);}); //it works
        log.info("finish"); //it works
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Logger.info` receives a `String`, so you have to convert your `MyPojo` to a string with `toString()`:

```
myPojos.stream().forEach((myPojo) -> {log.info(myPojo.toString());});
```

Note that since you have a single statement lambda, you can lose some of the robustness here:

```
myPojos.stream().forEach(myPojo -> log.info(myPojo.toString()));
```

Comment: Mureinik, thanks. I was so focused on trying lambda that I didn't note how simple was the error.

Answer (score 5):

Java 8 lambda style.
Add `@Slf4j` at the class level.

`myPojos.stream().forEach(log::info);`

Comment: does not work for me, i have error compilation below : Cannot resolve method 'info'

Comment: @Jacob Do you have a `log` variable in your class using `private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomItemWriter.class);` or @Slf4j at the class level?

Comment: Does not work, because Reference to 'info' is ambiguous, both 'info(String)' and 'info(String, Object)' match

Comment: do you have `@Slf4j` at the class level?